# how create a sql insert query from php select query

Tags: mysql

My problem:

I am trying to delete some important rows from multiple tables, around 20 tables, I am afraid that deleting the rows might cause some problem(I am not the creator of this website), so before deleting the rows I am selecting the rows and writing it into a file. But I write it as an array.

Is there a way to write it as an sql insert statement, to a file, so that it would be easy for me to update the database if there is some problem.

Comment: Can you post some code that you have already tried?

Answer (score 0):

For me it would be easier to store the information in a way that would allow me to understand the data.  Then ***IF*** I need it, I could mutate the data into an INSERT statement.

I strongly encourage you as a professional software engineer, to try not to solve a problem that you might encounter, until you ***DO*** encounter it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [`phpMyAdmin`](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) you can run a query that selects those rows, then click the Export link under `Query results operations`:

[image]

In the next page, select `Custom - display all possible options` and `SQL` Format:

[image]

Then, further down the page, select `data` under `Format specific options`:

[image]

And then press <kbd>Go</kbd>. You will be prompted to `Save or Open` a file, which will include the appropriate `INSERT` statements to recreate the data from those rows.